# How do I play audio in soundtouch?

Tags: c#, .net, soundtouch

How can I play audio using [soundtouch](https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/index.html)? I tried for a long time to find the answer on the Internet, but I couldn't find anything. Forgive me if the answer lies on the surface. It would also be cool to understand how to change the playback speed of an audio file.